# @Nullable annotation cannot be applied here

Tags: java, eclipse, language-lawyer, java-17, jsr305

Eclipse shows this as a Java problem:

> Annotation types that do not specify explicit target element types cannot be applied here.

This only happened when I upgraded from Eclipse 2022-09 to 2023-09.

This is an example when this happens:

```
public <T> @Nullable Set<T> getSomeSet(T something) {
  // ...
}
```

The annotation is the `javax.annotation.Nullable` from the jsr305 library.

I'm using Adoptium OpenJDK 17.0.8.101-hotspot.

- This didn't happen with Eclipse 2022-09.
- This doesn't happen with IntelliJ.
- This doesn't happen when I compile via `gradlew compileJava`.
- This doesn't happen with `public @Nullable Set<?> getSomeSet() { ... }`
- This doesn't happen with `public @Nullable <T> Set<T> getSomeSet(T something)`

I don't understand why is that happening in this specific circumstance now (and not in all other cases) and what can I do to make that error disappear from my Eclipse IDE. I didn't find any option to disable this kind of error in the preferences.

**EDIT:** Simplified the minimal reproduction case and added "doesn't happen" case #4.

**EDIT2:** Added "doesn't happen" case #5.

Comment: Works with 2023-06. Interestingly, the older version even allows to place such an annotation at a type parameter, which contradicts the specification (prior to Java 21). It seems, they tried to fix this and made it worse…

Comment: Just tried `public @Nullable <T> Set<T> getSomeSet(T something)` and it works! Now I wonder if that has the same semantics? If yes this might be a good solution. Would still be curious why the bad one still compiles fine with Gradle and other IDEs — also probably JSR305 is not even related as I get the same behaviour with "straighter" annotations like `@Deprecated`.

Comment: Compliance is JavaSE17 and I believe it's set automagically by reading `sourceCompatibility = '17'` from my _build.gradle_ file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may seem as if the declarations

```java
public <T> @Nullable Set<T> getSomeSet(T something)
public @Nullable <T> Set<T> getSomeSet(T something)
```

are syntactically different, i.e. that in the first variant, the annotation is bound to the return type. Apparently, Eclipse follows this idea.

The [grammar of the specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4), however, shows both as part of the method declaration:

> ```
> MethodDeclaration:
>     {MethodModifier} MethodHeader MethodBody
> MethodHeader:
>     Result MethodDeclarator [Throws]
>     TypeParameters {Annotation} Result MethodDeclarator [Throws]
> MethodDeclarator:
>     Identifier ( [ReceiverParameter ,] [FormalParameterList] ) [Dims]
> ```

[MethodModifier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3)

> ```
> MethodModifier:
>     (one of)
>     Annotation public protected private
>     abstract static final synchronized native strictfp
> ```

Note that `{Annotation}` between `TypeParameters` and `Result` is part of the `MethodHeader`.

Then the [Java Language Specification, §9.7.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.7.4) says:

> It is possible for an annotation to appear at a syntactic location in a program where it could plausibly apply to a declaration, or a type, or both.
>
> [...]
>
> The grammar of the Java programming language unambiguously treats annotations at these locations as modifiers for a declaration (§8.3), but that is purely a syntactic matter. Whether an annotation applies to the declaration or to the type of the declared entity - and thus, whether the annotation is a declaration annotation or a type annotation - depends on the applicability of the annotation's interface […]

The way I read this, is that the syntactic location shouldn’t matter, but only the applicability of annotation, given by the `@Target` annotation or its absence. That’s also, how `javac` handles this, unlike Eclipse:

```java
public class AnnotationExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchMethodException {
        Method m = AnnotationExample.class.getMethod("methodName");
        System.out.println("method:      " + Arrays.toString(m.getAnnotations()));
        System.out.println("return type: "
            + Arrays.toString(m.getAnnotatedReturnType().getAnnotations()));
    }

    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME) @Target({TYPE_USE, METHOD}) @interface A {}
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME) @Target({TYPE_USE, METHOD}) @interface B {}

    public static @A <T extends Enum<T>> @B Set<T> methodName() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

When compiled with `javac`, it will print

```
method:      [@AnnotationExample$A(), @AnnotationExample$B()]
return type: [@AnnotationExample$A(), @AnnotationExample$B()]
```

but when compiled with Eclipse, it prints

```
method:      [@AnnotationExample.A()]
return type: [@AnnotationExample.A(), @AnnotationExample.B()]
```

indicating that Eclipse treats the annotation behind the type parameter declaration as an annotation of the return type only. Consequently, changing `B`’s declaration to `@Target(METHOD)` produces a compile error in Eclipse.

---

This behavior interacts with the targets assumed to be valid when no `@Target` annotation has been given:

From Java 8 to Java 13, [the specification looked like](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6.4.1)

> If an annotation of type `java.lang.annotation.Target` is not present on the declaration of an annotation type `T`, then `T` is applicable in all declaration contexts except type parameter declarations, and in no type contexts.

Starting with Java 17, [the specification looks like](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6.4.1)

> If an annotation of type `java.lang.annotation.Target` is not present on the declaration of an annotation interface `A`, then `A` is applicable in all declaration contexts and in no type contexts.

So, this looks like a straight-forward change, now also permitting type parameter declarations as target when no `@Target` has been given, which does not affect our scenario.

If there weren’t the in-between versions, [14 to 16](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6.4.1):

> If an annotation of type java.lang.annotation.Target is not present on the declaration of an annotation interface A, then A is applicable in all nine declaration contexts and in all 16 type contexts.

<sup>(in Java 16, there are ten declaration contexts and 17 type contexts)</sup>

This directly affects compilers assuming that the annotation following the type parameter declaration are type contexts only. And since this is more permissive than the subsequent version, it’s understandable if a compiler vendor gets surprised by this and has to deliver the more restrictive behavior in an update.

(Note that `javac` dodged this by not implementing these changes in the first place, JDK 21 is the first to implement the behavior specified since Java 17, see [JDK-8309743](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8309743))

---

It’s important to keep in mind that while the compiler error shouldn’t happen, the specification changes will still affect what is reported to be annotated when inspecting the code. When you want to be able to annotate types, rather than the method, you need an explicit `@Target` including `TYPE_USE`.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer and the time you took for your thorough write-up. So let me try to summarise it: from what I've understood, Java 17 specs say `@Nullable` is targetless, therefore it can only apply to a declaration. But they also say that `public <T> @Xyz Set<T> methodName(...) { ... }` is a totally valid method declaration so the compiler SHOULD NOT complain, but if I meant the return type to be nullable the semantics would now be incorrect anyway. Therefore: 1) Eclipse compiler is bugged. 2) I should drop the `@Nullable` annotation anyway...

Comment: ...so even once the bug is fixed, I should still wait for any of the JSR305 implementations to add `@Target` to its nullability annotations. It was really hard to find any, but I'm seeing JetBrains does. But maybe it doesn't matter as it would depend on what the analysis tools do I guess.

Comment: Yes, the analysis tool must be able to cope with type annotations but if it ships with annotations not having `@Target(TYPE_USE)`, it’s a bad sign. It’s worth checking the tool’s documentation though, as it might be that the annotations are shipped in backwards compatible form but the tool can deal with adapted annotations. Before Java 8, there were no type annotations, so we had to annotate the member and the tool had to interpret this as annotation of the field type or method return type, by convention. However, that was a decade ago, so the tools should have managed to catch up…